# Power BI - Get ("running") minimum values for all dates per category

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I have two tables.
Table1: article numbers, categories
Table2: article numbers, dates, prices

The two tables are connected based on the article numbers. Each item number occurs once in the  Table1.

I would need a calculated table where all the dates and the minimum cost values would be listed per category.

The problem is that not all articles within a category have the same date. But I need the minimum value at all times. In other words, if I have a cost value of $10 for article 'A' on the first of January, then if I only have cost data for article 'B' for the second of January (e.g.: $12), then $10 should also be included in the table for the second of January.

Table1:

| Article | Category |
| --- | --- |
| A | cat1 |
| B | cat1 |
| C | cat2 |
| D | cat2 |
| E | cat3 |

Table2:

| Article | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01.01.2023 | $10 |
| A | 03.01.2023 | $10 |
| B | 02.01.2023 | $12 |
| B | 03.01.2023 | $11 |
| B | 04.01.2023 | $9 |
| C | 01.01.2023 | $10 |
| C | 02.01.2023 | $10 |
| D | 01.01.2023 | $11 |
| D | 04.01.2023 | $9 |
| F | 01.01.2023 | $8 |
| F | 02.01.2023 | $9 |
| F | 03.01.2023 | $7 |

Table result:

| Category | Date | MinPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat1 | 01.01.2023 | $10 |
| cat1 | 02.01.2023 | $10 |
| cat1 | 03.01.2023 | $10 |
| cat1 | 04.01.2023 | $9 |
| cat2 | 01.01.2023 | $10 |
| cat2 | 02.01.2023 | $10 |
| cat2 | 04.01.2023 | $9 |
| cat3 | 01.01.2023 | $8 |
| cat3 | 02.01.2023 | $8 |
| cat3 | 03.01.2023 | $7 |

How can I create this calculated table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could look like:

```
TableResult = 
  var tbl = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
      SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Table1'[Category], 'Table1'[Article], 'Table2'[Date] ),
      "Price",
        var thisDate = [Date]
        var thisArt = [Article]
        var fltr = FILTER('Table2', 'Table2'[Article] = thisArt && 'Table2'[Date] <= thisDate)
        return CALCULATE( MIN('Table2'[Price]), TOPN(1, fltr, [Date], DESC) )
    )
  return GROUPBY(tbl, [Category], [Date], "MinPrice", MINX(CURRENTGROUP(), [Price]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This seems to be a good solution. Unfortunately, I get an error message: 

"A single value for column 'Price' in 'table2' cannot be determined.  This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."

I changed the last row of dax, but now it shows the minimum value of table2 in all rows.

Comment: The above answer was for a Calculated Table. Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Do you want a measure?

Comment: sorry it was my fault. I found what I wrote wrong. What you sent works fine. Thanks again.